# Electron app with svelte devtools didn't detect my svelte

Tags: google-chrome-extension, electron, google-chrome-devtools, svelte

Building electron app with svelte frontend.
I have installed extension svelte devtools with

```js
  const {default: installExtension} = require('electron-devtools-installer');

  const installExtensions = () => {
    installExtension('ckolcbmkjpjmangdbmnkpjigpkddpogn') // ID OF SVELTE DEVTOOLS EXTENSION
      .then((name) => console.log(`Added Extension: ${name}`))
      .catch((error) => console.log('An error occured ', error));
  }
```

Whenever I open devtools and switch to svelte tab I got:

To connect to Svelte perform a hard refresh (ctrl+F5) or click here.

Not working? Did you...
Use Svelte version 3.12.0 or above?
Build with dev mode enabled?

Any help?

Comment: Are you using the standalone version of svelte devtools ?
If not, you should check this: https://github.com/RedHatter/svelte-devtools/issues/37#issuecomment-781622702

Comment: Are you compiling with the `dev` option https://svelte.dev/docs#compile-time-svelte-compile ?